# In Angular2+ is there a performance benefit to using [disabled] rather than "disabled" in a template

Tags: html, angular

Consider the two following HTML snippets

```
<input formControlName="address" [disabled]=isDisabled/>

<input formControlName="address" disabled={{isDisabled}}/>
```

Other than readability, my sense tells me that the first one is preferred over the second, but I am unable to find any information if this is true and why that might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions) evaluates the expression as a string, which can cause an incorrect behavior. For example, if you have:

```
isDisabled = false;
```

Using interpolation:

```
disabled="{{ isDisabled }}"
```

is equivalent to:

```
[disabled]="'false'"
```

which wrongly disables the button since the string `'false'` is truthy.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zm6t5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.